# Keras: Save Model In Suitable Format for Google Cloud ML Engine (missing functions)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to deploy a recently trained Keras model on Google Cloud ML Engine.  I googled around to see what format the saved model needs to be for ML Engine and found this:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import predict_signature_def

# reset session
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

# disable loading of learning nodes
K.set_learning_phase(0)

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')
config = model.get_config()
weights = model.get_weights()
new_Model = Sequential.from_config(config)
new_Model.set_weights(weights)

# export saved model
export_path = 'YOUR_EXPORT_PATH' + '/export'
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'NAME_YOUR_INPUT': new_Model.input},
                                  outputs={'NAME_YOUR_OUTPUT': new_Model.output})

with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                         tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={
                                             signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature})
    builder.save()
```

However, in Keras 2.1.3, `keras.backend` no longer seems to have `clear_session(), set_session()`, or `get_session()`.  What's the modern way of handling this issue?  Do those functions live elsewhere now?

Thanks!

Comment: Try tf.K.clear_session() as clear_session() is the up to date backend function

Comment: @d_kennetz do you mean `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`?  I'm not sure what `tf.K` refers to in your answer

Comment: Well you have tensorflow as tf and keras.backend as K so tf.K.clear_session()

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session As it is defined here.